# preg_replace - possible to check "outside" of the search pattern to determine whether to replace?

Tags: regex

I want to replace anything of the form `1/2` `3/4` `9 / 10` etc with `1-2`, `3-4`, `9-10`.  Two numbers, with a slash (with or without spaces) get converted to two numbers with a hyphen and no spaces.  This should work wherever in the input string the pattern is.  `foo 3/4 bar` -> `foo 3-4 bar`, etc.

(The numbers will always be consecutive like in my examples, but that's not important, I don't need to check for that.)

I have `preg_replace('/([0-9]+)\s?&\s?([0-9]+)/', '$1-$2', $foo);`

Which works great!

Except I have another rule.  If the first number is preceeded with a `U`, I don't with to perform a replacement.  So `U9/10` should stay as `U9/10`.

I can't work out how to make this happen.  I've tried adding `[^U]` at the start of the pattern, and inside the first containing group, but neither has the effect I'm looking for.

Is this possible with a single call to `preg_replace`, or do I need to run a `preg_match` first?

Comment: Then use `\b`,   a word boundary, `/\b([0-9]+)\s?\/\s?([0-9]+)/`. Or a lookbehind, `\b(?<!U)([0-9]+)\s?\/\s?([0-9]+)`

Comment: Lookbehind is the key technical term that I didn't know that I was looking for, thank you!